# task 1 for project

Tags: optimization

I need to produce code within Visual Basic that identify's a words position. For example, my sentence could write 'This is my Visual Basic Project'. If the user entered the word 'my', the output will open another form displaying 'Your word is in the 3rd position'. Its required to use strings then split it into an array, then using the match function give each word individual properties/positions.

I am fairly new to programming and would love any help. I would appreciate it if you could return some code for my design e.g buttons and listboxes. I have tried incredibly hard to get this program fully functioning but i'm finding it very challenging.

Really please. Many thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Basic: Identifying a word's position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920648/visual-basic-identifying-a-words-position)

Comment: You need to show some effort to get answers on here.. e.g. code and what you cant understand.... but do some research first... REad this.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789093.aspx especially the split function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I am not a Visual Basic or .NET person, but I really liked the problem and so optimization of my code is possible . I am little confused by, what do you mean by match function. Are you looking for REGEX or something for string matching over here? 
Anyways, based on your description, I tried to code something for you, which I think is something what you are looking for.

[image]

[image: A pop up message, which you can replace with another form too]

**CODE:**

The whole logic is within the click of the button "FIND POSITION OF WORD". Split the sentence then compare the entered word with each word in sentence

```
Public Class FindTheWord
Private Sub buttonFindTheWord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonFindTheWord.Click
    Dim inputSentence As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim inputWord As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim SplittedSentence As String() = inputSentence.Split(" ")
    Dim Position As Integer = 0
    For Each word In SplittedSentence
        Position = Position + 1
        If (word = inputWord) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Your word is at position : " + Position.ToString)
        End If
    Next
End Sub End Class
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this!! I will begin programming the code and feedback to you!

Comment: @K.Smith It will be great, if you can select this as the best answer :-)

Comment: My program is beginning to work, however it only seems to work with one word within the sentence box and also doesn't correlate with my list box, as it is still visible when running the program. To fix this, do lines 3,4,5 and 6 need to be public rather than in private?

Comment: please can you explain, why are you using Listbox?

Comment: Is there no need for a list box?

Comment: I want to make things little more clear. Do you want to add some words in your Listbox, and then check the position of each word taken from your listbox, in the main sentence?